# Intersecting circles (probability)

Tags: probability, geometry, circles

Here's a problem I have:

You have two unit squares, A and B, adjacent to each other (one side tangent). You randomly place 2 points in each Square. The two points in square A is a and b and the two points in square B is c and d. Now, you form a circle where one of the two points in each square lies on the periferi of the circle and the other point the centre. The ones who become the centre are the points in A and B that are closest to each other.

**Example:**

[image]

These two points become the centre of the two circles since they are closest to each other.

**Question:**

What is the probability that these two circles will intersect?

---

I haven't had much progress so far. I imagined a vertical axis in the middle of both squares. Placing points to the left or right of this line. Tried to see whether or not that would lead me to answer, but it didn't. It depends on where the other two points lie in the other square. So, I'm here to see if you guys can guide me in the right direction.

Comment: You need to be more clear. 1) "you form a circle with radius equal to the distance between the two points": which two points? 2) "choose the centre of these circles to be the points": how can a centre be more than one point?

Comment: 1) I mean one of the two points in each sqaure lies on the periferi of the circle and the other point is the centre. Regarding your question 2), i'll add an image what I mean,

Comment: @Marcel Is this more clear?

Comment: I think you should say what you said in your first comment in the question itself.

Comment: Alright, i'll edit